# How to group by 'row sets' in MySQL SELECT?

Tags: mysql

I have table `t` with combinations of columns `a` and `b` which have an `id` assigned. These combinations in `a` and `b` are repeating. For every such combination I want to determine all `id`s. Example:

```
+------+------+------+
| id   | a    | b    |
+------+------+------+
|    1 | A    | x    |
|    1 | B    | y    |
|    1 | C    | z    |
|    2 | A    | u    |
|    2 | B    | v    |
|    3 | A    | x    |
|    3 | B    | y    |
|    3 | C    | z    |
|    4 | A    | x    |
|    4 | B    | y    |
|    5 | A    | x    |
|    5 | B    | y    |
|    5 | C    | z    |
|    5 | D    | n    |
|    6 | A    | u    |
|    6 | B    | v    |
|    7 | A    | u    |
|    7 | B    | v    |
+------+------+------+
```

Now I want to get ids `1`and `3` for combination `(A,x),(B,y),(C,z)`. I want to get ids `2`, `6` and `7` for combination `(A,u),(B,v)`. ids `4` and `5` are distinct from `1` (for `4` one row is missing, for `5` there is one row too much) and hence should be reported separately:

```
(A,x),(B,y),(C,z): 1,3
(A,u),(B,v): 2,6,7
(A,x),(B,y): 4
(A,x),(B,y),(C,z),(D,n): 5
```

How to query MySQL for this grouping?

SQL code to setup the example table:

```
CREATE TABLE t (id int, a VARCHAR(4), b VARCHAR(4));
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, 'A', 'x');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, 'B', 'y');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, 'C', 'z');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (2, 'A', 'u');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (2, 'B', 'v');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (3, 'A', 'x');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (3, 'B', 'y');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (3, 'C', 'z');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (4, 'A', 'x');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (4, 'B', 'y');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (5, 'A', 'x');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (5, 'B', 'y');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (5, 'C', 'z');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (5, 'D', 'n');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (6, 'A', 'u');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (6, 'B', 'v');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (7, 'A', 'u');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (7, 'B', 'v');
```

Comment: Why these specific? Why not `(A,x),(B,y): 1,3,4,5`?

Comment: Because `[(A,x),(B,y)]`, `[(A,x),(B,y),(C,z)]` and `[(A,x),(B,y),(C,z),(D,n)` are different combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can first get all the combinations in a particular `id` using `Concat()` with `Group_Concat()`. We can also ensure that `(a,b)` is treated same as `(b,a)` using `Greatest()` and `Least()` functions. **Note** that if `(b,a)` should not be treated same as `(a,b)`, then you can get rid of the usage of `Greatest()` and `Least()` in the below query.

In the `Group_Concat()`, we also order them up, so that we dont get two separate combinations as: `(a,b), (c,d)` and `(c,d), (a,b)`. Ordering ensures that we only get: `(a,b), (c,d)` for both the cases.

Finally, use this result-set in a Derived Table, and now aggregate all the id(s) having same set of combinations.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE t (id int, a VARCHAR(4), b VARCHAR(4));
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, 'A', 'x');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, 'B', 'y');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, 'C', 'z');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (2, 'A', 'u');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (2, 'B', 'v');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (3, 'A', 'x');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (3, 'B', 'y');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (3, 'C', 'z');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (4, 'A', 'x');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (4, 'B', 'y');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (5, 'A', 'x');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (5, 'B', 'y');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (5, 'C', 'z');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (5, 'D', 'n');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (6, 'A', 'u');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (6, 'B', 'v');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (7, 'A', 'u');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (7, 'B', 'v');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
  dt.combinations, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(dt.id) AS ids 
FROM 
(
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT 
      CONCAT('(', LEAST(a,b), ',', GREATEST(a,b), ')') 
    ORDER BY 
      CONCAT('(', LEAST(a,b), ',', GREATEST(a,b), ')') ASC) AS combinations, 
  id 
FROM t
GROUP BY id
) dt 
GROUP BY dt.combinations;

| combinations            | ids   |
| ----------------------- | ----- |
| (A,u),(B,v)             | 2,6,7 |
| (A,x),(B,y)             | 4     |
| (A,x),(B,y),(C,z)       | 1,3   |
| (A,x),(B,y),(C,z),(D,n) | 5     |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3YAGWApTSNVVvko8Tikmvn/2)

Comment: Thanks! That is definitely going to work. For my use case even a slightly simpler version is sufficient:

`SELECT dt.combinations,
       group_concat(dt.id) AS ids
FROM
(
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT
    CONCAT(a,b)
  ORDER BY
    CONCAT(a,b)) AS combinations,
  id
FROM t
GROUP BY id
) dt
GROUP BY dt.combinations;`

The data will be processed in Java. Do you have a suggestion on how to change the SELECT to return less concat-strings but more structured data instead? E.g. the `id`s as INT in multiple rows?

Comment: @mstrap I think you are looking for this (run this fiddle) --> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3YAGWApTSNVVvko8Tikmvn/3

Comment: You don't need CONCAT() within GROUP_CONCAT()

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I know, but I prefer using `Concat()` for code clarity (even at the cost of making it more verbose)